# Flashing 2.3.3 'Leaky' onto a Samsung Epic 4G

Tags: rom-flashing, samsung-epic-4g

What can go wrong when flashing an unstable Android OS onto a phone? Is there an easy way to reset the phone if something goes wrong?  Has anyone out there had experience flashing Android OS?

Why would I want to flash [Gingerbread 2.3.3 aka Leaky](http://mobile.engadget.com/2011/05/02/android-2-3-3-leaked-for-samsung-epic-4g-dubbed-leaky-for-goo/) onto my Samsung Epic 4G?

One benefit that I can see is that users of the Epic will be able to test their applications on > Froyo 2.2.1, which is currently the stable release for the phone.

*EDIT:* Also, what happens when the device wants to update again, say 2.3.4 is flashed onto the phone, and then Sprint finally releases a stable 2.3.4 in 2013.  Assuming I still have this phone then, will it upgrade gracefully from the flashed ROM?

Comment: Questions that ask "in your opinion" are generally not the kind of questions we're looking for here. The kind of questions we like have (the potential for) a single, concrete answer.

Comment: "Is it a good idea" is still asking for opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything can go wrong, including issues that permanently brick the device.

That said, Galaxy S devices are compatible with a tool called Odin that can fix all but the worst problems.  [Example process](http://www.jaredlog.com/?p=1165).

I personally flash pretty much anything I feel like onto my Vibrant, and Odin has saved me many times.  I wouldn't hesitate to flash something I wanted to try out, but you may wish to be more cautious.

Comment: Can't emphasize enough that for the phone the question is about (Epic) bricking is significantly low-risk. See instructions http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1052813 on XDA for details.

Comment: Also, 2.3.3 might not add much, but the more recent 2.3.4 leaks are supposed to allow for google video chat with the front camera. That's huge.